# Printing to (and overwriting) same line for a status indicator

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I am running the following on Mac OSX and Python 3. I am running the snippet using Sublime Text 3's default build system for Python 3 and displaying the output in the same program's output window.

```
print('Starting test.')
for i in range(1,100):
    print('This is a test. ' + str(i), end='\r')
print('Test done!')
```

My desired output is basically a repetition of that same line, overwriting the previous line in the console each time. By the end, I should ideally only see the following in my output window.

```
 Starting test.
 This is a test. 99
 Test done!
```

I would expect the `end='\r'` gets me to this behavior, but it doesn't. Instead, I see:

```
 Starting test.
 This is a test. 1
 This is a test. 2
 This is a test. 3
 [...]
 This is a test. 99
 Test done!
```

Comment: I can't recreate you error. How are you executing it? Directly from console command?

Comment: Actually, I just checked it on a seperate machine and it seems to work fine. I was running it from within Sublime3, so it would appear it has to do with the environment in there. Whoops. I'm trying to narrow it down.

Comment: Yep, looks like I was chasing a ghost. The code works as expected in a regular Python command line, but Sublime's build system wasn't showing me the correct line ending when I gave it command+B.

Comment: @BradleyEvans Consider editing your own question (to say that you're using Sublime text) and add a self answer.

Answer (score 2):

For background, if you use `View Package File` from the command palette to view `Default/exec.py` you can examine the code that's being used to execute programs and display their output into the panel.

As a short synopsis, the program is executed in a background thread, and the output of `stdout` and `stderr` are read from using this code:

```python
def read_fileno(self, fileno, execute_finished):
    decoder_cls = codecs.getincrementaldecoder(self.listener.encoding)
    decoder = decoder_cls('replace')
    while True:
        data = decoder.decode(os.read(fileno, 2**16))

        if len(data) > 0:
            if self.listener:
                self.listener.on_data(self, data)
        else:
            try:
                os.close(fileno)
            except OSError:
                pass
            if execute_finished and self.listener:
                self.listener.on_finished(self)
            break
```

That is, whenever they read any data, they invoke `on_data()` in the object that's listening for results, which in this case is the `exec` command itself. The implementation of that method looks like this:

```python
def on_data(self, proc, data):
    # Normalize newlines, Sublime Text always uses a single \n separator
    # in memory.
    data = data.replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n')

    self.append_string(proc, data)
```

Internally Sublime uses `\n` as the line separator, so on windows `\r\n` is interpreted as `\n`, and on MacOS `\r` is interpreted as `\n` as well.

So on the one hand this doesn't do what you expect because your `\r` is effectively treated the same as `\n` is.

Aside of that, if you trace the call to `append_string()` through the guard code that keeps it thread safe and allows it to interact with the Sublime core, it ends up in a line that looks like this:

```python
    self.output_view.run_command(
        'append',
        {'characters': characters, 'force': True, 'scroll_to_end': True})
```

That is, whatever characters you provide, they're directly appended to the output buffer without regard to what they might contain.

If you were to provide a custom build `target` (a somewhat advanced plugin but still possible) this behaviour could be modified, although it might be tricky to get it to work on MacOS since there would be no way to distinguish what `\r` means on that platform.

Answer (score 1):

The code displays correctly in a normal command line window. The problem is with Sublime's output window, which doesn't seem to be displaying the carriage return correctly (it replaces it with a newline).

Answer (score -1):

Actually you need to add '\r' at the beginning of the string.

```
print('Starting test.')
for i in range(1,100):
    print('\rThis is a test.'+str(i), end="")
print('\nTest done!')
```

**Output**

```
Starting test.
This is a test.99
Test done!
```

Comment: This is not OP's issue. As OP said, it's because of Sublime Text's console.

Comment: Okay. But I believe this is also another method to get the same output. It may help some people in future.